# CDI on GlassFish 3.1.1 b12 generates error "WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies"

Tags: glassfish-3, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm trying to evaluate CDI on Glassfish 3.1 and even though I have accomplished to make it work well, when I'm trying to split my code in separate deployment modules I get a weird error. More specifically:

I have two classes bundled in the same utility project (let's say the `CommonLib.jar`); the classnames are `UserDatabase` and `UserDatabaseEntityManager` and their definitions are as below (in the PS at the end of this message).
I also have an EAR with an EJB3.1 module in it.

When I choose to deploy the `CommonLib.jar` as a "Bundled Library" of the EAR, then I get the following error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : `WELD-001408` Unsatisfied dependencies for type [`EntityManager`] with qualifiers [`@UserDatabase`] at injection point [[field] `@UserDatabase @Inject com.test.TestEJB.itemPersistenceEm`]. Please see `server.log` for more details.

Same error as above I get also when I deploy the CommonLib.jar as a shared library (jar file copied under `$glasshfish_installation_path/domains/domain1/lib`)
BUT, if I choose to just have the two classes (`UserDatabase` and `UserDatabaseEntityManager`) in the EJB project (thus they are compiled within the EJB module), then the injection works fine.

Am I facing a classloader issue? Any ideas how I can get past this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, because I faced a very similar problem with Glassfish and CDI a few days ago: Do you have a `beans.xml` in *every* JAR, i.e. in the `CommonLib.jar` and the EJB JAR, so that CDI scans both of them?

My problem resulted from the fact that I thought placing a `beans.xml` into the EAR would be sufficient, which is not the case.

Comment: You just save a whole night of my life. An interface in ejb-jar contained in a war hadn't been resolved for 5 hours. Now I can go home. I love you. Will you marry me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running into some of the Glassfish CDI integration issues we've found [while working on Seam 3](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/Compatibility). It could be a couple of them, so you'll have to take a look at see which one it may be. Try testing on JBoss AS7 or Apache TomEE and see if you still have problems.